# Does Telegram send message using peer-to-peer connection?

Tags: networking, peer-to-peer, telegram-messenger

I recently learned that when using telegram for calls, it tries to use peer-to-peer connections for communication, but I wonder if it also uses peer-to-peer communication when sending messages?

**If so, when I send a message to a group of 100 people, do I send the message directly from my phone to each of the 100 people in telegram?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Telegram only has full secure end-to-end encryption for "Secret chats". This is the only client-client end-to-end encrypted functionallity in Telegram, whereas the rest is client-server/server-client. So group messaging goes over Telegram's cloud infrastructure, where you send once and Telegram forwards to 100 people. You can find all this information on Telegram's website in the [FAQ](https://telegram.org/faq)